# How do you put a space after every period that isn't a part of a decimal number in python?

Tags: python, regex

I tried writing a regular expression to replace `'.'` with `'. '`.

However it splits decimal numbers such as `'2.5'` to `'2. 5'`.

Is there anyway to do this without separating decimal numbers? This is what I have:

```
re.sub('(?![0-9]+)(\.)(?<![0-9])', '. ', some_string)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lookarounds look in the wrong direction:

```
re.sub('(?<![0-9])\.(?![0-9])', '. ', some_string)
```

In front of the `.`, you want to look**behind** that there was no digit before. After the `.`, you want to look**ahead** that there is no digit next. Checking for multiple digits (with the `+`) doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

You have misplaced the *look-ahead* and *look-behind*:

It should be:

```
re.sub('(?<![0-9])[.](?![0-9])', '. ', some_string)
```